# What is "Total number of votes for 'N' answer" in "Deleted Recent Answers"?

Tags: discussion, help, deleted-posts-pages

What is "Total number of votes for 'N' answer" in "Deleted Recent Answers"?

> [image]

What I tried :

[Help 1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=%22Total%20number%20of%20votes%20for%22)
[Help 2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=Total%20number%20of%20votes%20for%20%27N%27%20answer)

---

I am able to view this page by below shown in image

> [image]

Comment: From where did you find *Deleted Recent Answers*?

Comment: @hims056 It is part of your profile now. Go to the "Answers" tab, and click the link at the very bottom. It also exists for questions.

Comment: @CodyGray - Ohh So finally the most wanted feature request is completed.

Comment: Wow!! Nice to have this feature.. But the question is really valid.. I [have 1 of the question deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/2345913) which had one downvote.. but in recent deleted answer says `total number of votes for answer` = 0 ?? How come??

Comment: I am not sure how many can see the link I mentioned above may be mods or SE dev only??

Comment: @CRUSADER Only you and mods. Mods can also see your deleted answers directly in the main answers tab.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, Right!! I realised that too, as it was my deleted content and others have nothing to do with it... By the way, the issue I mentioned above is already raised by the same OP [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193169/221351).. I must say he was faster than me :P