# "Total number of votes for 'N' answers" is wrong in "Deleted Recent Answers"

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, vote-count, deleted-posts-pages

Below are the two screenshots.
First one shows the number of votes

> [image]

---

In above image a post which was deleted shown ) votes. Now in below image which is actual post deleted is having 1 vote.

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Starting with `rev 2014.6.12.2312` here on meta and `rev 2014.6.12.1659` everywhere else, we'll show both the correct score *and* the correct tooltip for each answer on that view.

Comment: Cool, do you think you can get the ['delete votes' bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233537/mouseover-tooltip-for-delete-count-is-wrong) fixed also?