# Mouseover tooltip for delete count is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete, tooltips

Normally, it takes three votes to delete.  It still does, though the mouseover tip for a question with one delete vote cast on it already appears to be stuck at '1'

[image: Before]

And then after casting a delete vote on it:

[image: After]

And if I've cast the first delete vote:

[image]

The above examples are from P.SE, and while I don't have the privs to verify this being the situation on other sites, this has been confirmed on at least SO and is likely network wide.

---

Child meta dups:

- SO: [1 more vote from other users is needed to delete this post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265308/289086)

Comment: This also occurs on undelete votes: [Confusion about how many votes are needed to undelete a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233807/152515)

Comment: I'm taking a look at this now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was due to a very small logic error in our code. I have patched it up and you'll see it live in the next release! (Meta: > rev `2014.7.11.2366`, Sites: > rev `2014.7.11.1701`)

Answer (score 7):

If you notice in your first example, it's actually an even deeper problem.  I've been checking delete totals on popular questions, and most show '1 more vote...'.  My assumption is that if it takes double digits to delete/undelete, then it is only showing '1'.  So they really need to look at that number logic.