# Confusion about how many votes are needed to undelete a post

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

I went to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545136/is-literate-programming-dead) (deleted, so 10K+ only) and pressed the "undelete" link. As you can see in the following screenshots, there are discrepancies in what it tells me about how many votes are needed to undelete the post.

First, it says 1 more vote is needed.

[image: 1 more vote is needed to undelete this post]

Then it says there are 22 votes remaining. I am not sure if this is supposed to be the number of undelete votes I have left or the number of votes still required to undelete the post.

[image: Vote to undelete this post? (22 votes remaining)]

Apparently, even though earlier my vote was the only one needed to undelete the post, now yet another vote is required. (Also note the minor pluralization bug; it reads better as "1 more vote from another user" instead of "1 more vote from other users".)

[image: You voted to undelete. 1 more vote from other users is needed to undelete this post.]

What's going on here? How many undelete votes would this question actually need to be undeleted?

---

Side note: I don't really care much about whether or not this post should be undeleted; I clicked through just to document the discrepancy.

Comment: (I don't see a pluralization bug, for what it's worth)

Comment: (One vote can only come from one user. "1 more vote from other users" sounds strange to me unless multiple users could form one vote together)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but if I see "1 more vote from another user", I think that it's talking about some special user. By saying "users" in the plural, I think of it as "we need 1 more vote out of this group of people who can vote", which is exactly what it's trying to say.

Answer (score 6):

It takes three delete votes to delete a post.

There's two things going on here.

## The 22 votes thing

> Then it says there are 22 votes remaining. I am not sure if this is supposed to be the number of undelete votes I have left or the number of votes still required to undelete the post.

The '22' is the number of delete votes you can cast today. You can vote to delete 22 more questions. This is just like the cap on close votes, flags, and upvotes/downvotes.

## The 1 more vote thing

This is a bug; your confusion is totally justified. **undelete(1)** requires *two* more delete votes to delete, but the tooltip's wrong.

It may be related to this one: [Mouseover tooltip for delete count is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233537/mouseover-tooltip-for-delete-count-is-wrong)

Comment: FYI I fixed the tooltip display. This was due to a very small logic error in our code. I have patched it up and you'll see it live in the next release! (Meta: > rev `2014.7.11.2366`, Sites: > rev `2014.7.11.1701`)

Comment: Thanks for fixing it and letting us know :D